# Callback from InAppBrowser executeScript doesn't run on IOS. Phonegap/Cordova

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins, inappbrowser

I'm working on a Facebook-login feature for my Cordova-application, where I'm using the InAppBrowser to perform the login. From there I'm trying to use the executeScript-method to grab the data from the InAppBroswer and return it to my main application (which is run on a server, not locally on the phone). This works perfectly on Android, but not in IOS (where none of the callback-methods are called). Perhaps anyone around here might be able to help me?

The following JavaScript-files are included in the main application on the server..

For IOS:

```
cordova.js (3.6.4)
cordova_plugins.js
index.js
```

For Android

```
cordova.js (3.7.0)
cordova_plugins.js
index.js
```

When running the code on Android i get the following result:

- InAppBrowser opens
- I log on to facebook
- I'm redirected back to the page displayed below  (code snippet no. 2)
- I receive an alert from the test()-function in the InAppBrowser (code snippet no. 2)
- I receive an alert from the first callback-function in the main app (code snippet no. 1)
- I receive an alert from the second callback-function in the main app  (code snippet no. 1)
- I'm logged in (result of the code-snippet removed from the code below) (code snippet no. 1)

When I'm running the code on IOS I get the followinf result:

- InAppBrowser opens
- I log on to facebook
- I'm redirected back to the page displayed below (code snippet no. 2)
- I receive an alert from the test()-function in the InAppBrowser (code snippet no. 2)

..but none of the callback funtions are called. So "d" keeps repeating..

And to make thins worse. The code has worked twice on IOS too. But only twice. Without me making any changes to it.

**[Edit]**

*It appeares that my problem occures due to the work flow in the InAppBrowser.
This is my current flow..*

- InAppBrowser luanches and page is redirected to Facebook's login api
- User performs login on facebook
- Return to my server from facebook, where code snippet no.2 is run
- All callbacks are fired on android, but not on IOS (see workflow abode for android/ios)

*When I tried this flow (which won't work with a login), the callbacks are fired..*

- Load InAppBrowser directly at the code in code snippet no.2
- All callbacks are fired on all browsers

**[/Edit]**

The code I'm using to open the InAppBrowser, and later collect data from it, looks like this:

```
function facebookLoginApp() {
var fbloginwin = window.open("/p/ajax/facebookLoginRedirect","_blank",'');

fbloginwin.addEventListener('loadstart',function() {
    clearInterval(loop);
    var loop = setInterval(function() {
        fbloginwin.executeScript( {code: "test();"},function(values) { alert("returnvalue " + values); });

        fbloginwin.executeScript(
            {
                code: "localStorage.getItem('userid')"
            },
            function( values ) {
                var userid = values[ 0 ];
                alert("Loadstart userId: " + userid);
                //Some code removed here for more readable sample..
            }
        );
        fbloginwin.executeScript(
            {
                code: "localStorage.getItem('error')"
            },
            function( values ) {
                var error = values[ 0 ];

                // If a name was set, clear the interval and close the InAppBrowser.
                if ( error ) {
                    clearInterval( loop );
                    fbloginwin.close();
                    alert("Login failed: \n" +error);
                }
            }
        );
    },5000);
});

fbloginwin.addEventListener('loadstop',function() {
    clearInterval(loop);
    var loop = setInterval(function() {
        fbloginwin.executeScript(
            {
                code: "localStorage.getItem('userid')"
            },
            function( values ) {
                var userid = values[ 0 ];
                alert("Loadstop userid " + userid);
                //Some code removed here for more readable sample..
            }
        );
        fbloginwin.executeScript(
            {
                code: "localStorage.getItem('error')"
            },
            function( values ) {
                var error = values[ 0 ];

                // If a name was set, clear the interval and close the InAppBrowser.
                if ( error ) {
                    clearInterval( loop );
                    fbloginwin.close();
                    alert("Login failed: \n" +error);
                }
            }
        );
    },5000);
});
}
```

And the code inside the InAppBrowser looks like this:

```
<html>
<script>
    function test() {
        alert("12341234");
        return "12341234";
    }
    window.localStorage.setItem("userid","12341234");
    window.localStorage.setItem("error","");

    alert(window.localStorage.getItem("userid"));
</script>
<body>
    Login successful. You will be redirected shortly.
</body>
</html>
```